# How do get from $|0\rangle=\alpha|a\rangle+\beta|b\rangle$, $|1\rangle=\gamma|a\rangle+\delta|b\rangle$ to an expression for $|01\rangle-|10\rangle$?

Tags: quantum-state, textbook-and-exercises, nielsen-and-chuang, bell-basis

My question is linked to the Nielsen Chuang book. Particularly equation 2.216 on basis change from $|0\rangle$, $|1\rangle$ to orthonormal $|a\rangle$ and $|b\rangle$. How do we get the equation from the following?

[image]

I understand everything except why we get the negative sign in the coefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just algebra because $(a-b)|u\rangle + (c-d)|v\rangle = (a-b)|u\rangle - (d-c)|v\rangle $.

To be more explicit to the problem, first note that:

\begin{align}
|01\rangle = \big( \alpha |a\rangle + \beta |b\rangle\big) \otimes \big(\gamma |a\rangle + \delta |b\rangle \big) = \alpha \gamma |aa\rangle + \alpha \delta |ab\rangle + \beta \gamma |ba\rangle + \beta \delta |bb\rangle
\end{align}
and similarly
\begin{align}
|10\rangle =  \big( \gamma |a\rangle + \delta |b\rangle \big) \otimes \big( \alpha |a\rangle + \beta |b\rangle\big) = \gamma \delta|aa\rangle + \gamma \beta |ab\rangle + \delta \alpha |ba\rangle +  \delta \beta |bb\rangle
\end{align}

and so

\begin{align}
\dfrac{|01\rangle - |10\rangle}{\sqrt{2}} &= \dfrac{\alpha \gamma |aa\rangle + \alpha \delta |ab\rangle + \beta \gamma |ba\rangle + \beta \delta |bb\rangle}{\sqrt{2}} \\ 
&- \\
&\hspace{0.6 cm}\frac{\gamma \delta|aa\rangle + \gamma \beta |ab\rangle + \delta \alpha |ba\rangle +  \delta \beta |bb\rangle}{\sqrt{2}} \\
&= 0 + \dfrac{\big(\alpha \delta - \gamma \beta \big)|ab\rangle}{\sqrt{2}} + \dfrac{\big( \beta\gamma - \delta \alpha\big) |ba\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}  + 0 \\
&= \dfrac{\big(\alpha \delta - \gamma \beta \big)|ab\rangle - \big(  \delta \alpha -\beta\gamma \big) |ba\rangle}{\sqrt{2}} \\
&= \dfrac{\big(\alpha \delta - \gamma \beta \big)|ab\rangle - \big(   \alpha \delta -\gamma \beta\big) |ba\rangle}{\sqrt{2}} \\
&= \big(\alpha \delta - \gamma \beta \big)  \dfrac{|ab\rangle - |ba\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{align}